# Как исправить ошибку API

Tags: c#, microsoft-store

> Supported APIs Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the
>   following errors: API ExecuteAssembly in uwphost.dll is not supported
>   for this application type. Archer Evolution.exe calls this API. API
>   DllGetActivationFactory in uwphost.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. Archer Evolution.exe has an export that forwards to
>   this API. API OpenSemaphore in api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll is not
>   supported for this application type. System.Threading.dll calls this
>   API. API CreateSemaphore in api-ms-win-core-kernel32-legacy-l1-1-0.dll
>   is not supported for this application type. System.Threading.dll calls
>   this API. API D3D12GetDebugInterface in d3d12.dll is not supported for
>   this application type. UnityPlayer.dll calls this API. Impact if not
>   fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows
>   Store apps violates the Windows Store certification requirements.  How
>   to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part
>   of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps. Please note, apps that are
>   built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where
>   applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in
>   unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with
>   .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more
>   information:  Alternatives to Windows APIs in Windows Store apps.

Вот такую ошибку выдаёт при проверке игры на Windows App Certification Kit. Где находится эти API и как можно исправить?

Comment: А вы тестируете таки Release и с включённым .NET Native?

Comment: Да Release. А как включить .NET Native?